# How to add pagination for wordpress home page

Tags: php, pagination

Hi I am using thevoux theme for my website as i need to add pagination links like "Older Posts and Newer Posts" to home page.Here is an example screen shot how it should be.
[image]

Actually right now i am getting these links in menus in the same way i need to display them in home page as well.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
$blog_featured = ot_get_option('blog_featured');
?>
<?php if ($blog_featured) { ?>
<div class="row header_content">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <?php 
            $args = array(
                'p' => $blog_featured,
                'post_type' => 'any'
            );
            $featured_post = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

        <?php if ($featured_post->have_posts()) :  while ($featured_post->have_posts()) : $featured_post->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'inc/loop/blog-featured' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>  
<?php } ?>

<div class="row">
<section class="blog-section small-12 medium-8 columns">
    <div class="row" data-equal=">.columns">
        <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'inc/loop/blog-list' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'inc/loop/notfound' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() || get_previous_posts_link()) { ?>
    <div class="blog_nav">
        <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo next_posts(); ?>" class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> <?php _e( 'Older Posts', 'thevoux' ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo previous_posts(); ?>" class="prev"><?php _e( 'Newer Posts', 'thevoux' ); ?> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: dowwnvoted as it seems to be a theme specific question (at least there is nothing wrong with the snippet provided, nor there is an explanation of what was tried and how it failed)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar on my blog too.  I used the following code to add the necessary links (adjust as required)

```
<?php previous_posts_link(__( '<button class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp; Newer Posts</button>' )) ?>
<?php next_posts_link(__( '<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Older Posts &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>' )) ?>
```

Comment: Alternatively ... Consider using a wordpress plugin.
e.g. - WP-PageNavi - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: Can you please share me where i need to add these code which you have sent here.I mean to say the file name

Comment: It all depends on the theme.  What theme are you using?  or is it custom developed?

Comment: I am using thevoux theme

Comment: can you mention where i need to add this code

Comment: This will usually be your index.php file. Scroll down to just before the end of the loop. This is after the “endwhile” statement but before any “else” statements within the loop.   I've also posted another alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found another option, as per the following page:
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-pagination-to-wordpress

Add the following code at the end of your theme's functions.php file

```
function pagination_nav() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
        <nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts' ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?></div>
        </nav>
<?php }
}
```

Then add the following line to your theme (where you need the pagination to be displayed)

```
<?php pagination_nav(); ?>
```

This will usually be your index.php file.  Scroll down to just before the end of the loop. This is after the “endwhile” statement but before any “else” statements within the loop.

Comment: Actually i have tried with the same code but it is not working

Comment: I have updated my index.php file can you please update where i need to add these <?php pagination_nav();?>

Comment: As I mentioned before it will usually be at the bottom - Have a look at how I implemented mine - http://pastebin.com/0GGAx8Tr

It's obviously different... But it depends on the theme.

Answer (score 0):

put this following code in your function.php file

```
function numeric_posts_nav() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

and put this line in your theme’s index.php, archive.php, category.php, and any other archive page template where you like to see pagination.

```
<?php numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

Comment: Not working not getting links in home page i have added in index.php file

Comment: this code is working completely in my project.

Comment: which kind of error are you getting when running this code?

Comment: It is not displaying any error

Answer (score 0):

this is proper working code for pagination on forntpage

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $paged
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title(); the_content();
endwhile;
```

and pagination code here

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
  'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
) );
```